# two api calls in custom alexa skill

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, alexa-skills-kit

I've asked this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489268/alexa-steam-custom-skill-api-integration?noredirect=1#comment70188757_41489268), but it may be a little too in depth for everyone to read through, but i suppose my basic question could be reduced to:

is it possible to do two separate API calls within the same piece JS code when writing a custom alexa skill?

Here's my logic

1. call steam api,
2. get details from my friends list
3. return details to alexa

4.create new API url with returned friends IDs

5.call new URL to get friends online status and names

6.return these details to alexa to sort and determine online status

7.construct speech response

8.say response

I've got it as far as constructing the API url with the friends IDs but it appears that my second API call either isn't working or i'm just not accessing it properly.

any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code can do anything you want (including multiple external API calls) in the process of handling an Alexa request, but you can only return one response to Alexa in fulfillment its request.

The steps could be itemized like this

1. Receive request from Alexa,
2. Do whatever processing you want, including multiple external API calls, but don't take too long as the user is waiting!
3. Formulate your response and return it to Alexa as the response to #1.
4. Continue processing, eg. to save some session or user data, but you can't send any more data to Alexa because you've already responded to its request.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: it does Tom, thanks. Now I know it can be done, it's just the how! I've been told that I should be looking at using promises to accomplish this and i've checked them out and have some understanding of how they work, but currently have no idea how to apply them to my code. (the code that I linked to in the question). Any tips on that front?

Comment: That's very different - that's a js implementation detail.  You will need to get some good resources/tutorials on js.  Fortunately there are tons of those!  (Please mark the answer as accepted.)